# Custom WooCommerce fee disappears at checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I add a custom fee on `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'delivery_surcharge');
function delivery_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;
    // ...
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Delivery fee', $fee, false, '');
}
```

But as soon as the user clicks checkout the fee is removed and not calculated towards the total.

I've verified that the fee has not yet been removed when `woocommerce_checkout_process` is called by performing the below check:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'checkout_validator');
function checkout_validator() {
    global $woocommerce;
    wc_add_notice($woocommerce->cart->get_total(), 'error');
}
```

Which gave me an error on checkout showing a total which included the custom fee. However, when I clicked checkout a second time, the fee had disappeared and `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` needed to be called a second time for it to reappear.

Furthermore, the fee is also present in the array returned by `WC_Cart::get_fees()` when checked in `woocommerce_checkout_process`.

**Edit:** Please see update 5.

## Related questions

[“Woocommerce won't add my custom fee to the cart total”—Related but with no useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844056/woocommerce-wont-add-my-custom-fee-to-the-cart-total)

## Updates

**Update 1:**
I added the following to `WC_Checkout::create_order()`:

```
  251 // Store fees
+ 252 error_log(print_r(WC()->cart->get_fees(), true));
  253 foreach ( WC()->cart->get_fees() as $fee_key => $fee ) {
```

An empty array was output meaning that the fees are removed sometime between the checkout processing and the order creation.

**Update 2:**
I performed another debug check similar to the above, this time by adding to `WC_Shortcode_Checkout::checkout()`:

```
  230 // Check cart has contents
  231 if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
  232     return;
  233 }
+ 234   
+ 235 error_log(print_r(WC()->cart->get_fees(), true));
  236
  237 // Check cart contents for errors
  238 do_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' );
```

The result was yet again an empty array.

**Update 3:**
Finally, some progress! I performed a similar check again, this time on `WC_Checkout::process_checkout()` which is called by `WC_Ajax::checkout()`:

```
  359 if ( ! defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT' ) ) {
  360     define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
  361 }
+ 362
+ 363 error_log(print_r(WC()->cart->get_fees(), true));
  364
  365 // Prevent timeout
  366 @set_time_limit(0);
```

And the fee actually showed up in `error_log`!

```
[12-Aug-2016 13:45:24 UTC] Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => delivery-fee
            [name] => Delivery fee
            [amount] => 4
            [tax_class] => 
            [taxable] => 
            [tax] => 0
            [tax_data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I'll continue to track through this function until I (hopefully) discover the exact location at which the fee is unset.

**Update 4:** I've managed to track down that the fee is unset somewhere after `WC_Cart::calculate_totals()` is called by `WC_Checkout::process_checkout()`. Investigating further.

**Update 5:** I have fully located the issue. Apparently `WC_Cart::calculate_totals()` calls `WC_Cart::reset()` which unsets all fees. I'm not sure how this ever worked but somehow, previously, the fee survived the call to `WC_Cart::reset()`. At this point I'm not sure whether this is a bug in my implementation or in WooCommerce itself.

Comment: Note: Instead using `global $woocommerce; $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Delivery fee', $fee, false, '');` you can just use **`WC()->cart`** syntax instead, so you will not need anymore `global $woocommerce;`… So you will have only: **`WC()->cart->add_fee('Delivery fee', $fee, false, '');`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted it out myself. Turns out it was an issue with `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` not being called correctly in my specific, outdated, version of WooCommerce. Updating solved the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue and cant get it running. Updating woocommerce is not the case today :-/.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the the action that resets the fees with this code.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_cart_reset', array(WC()->cart->fees_api(), 'remove_all_fees'));
```

Comment: This causes a fatal error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fees_api() on null`